# Where is the subject?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms, sentence-meaning

> "Donald Trump’s desire to nominate Mr Cain had sparked a backlash, even among Republicans worried that the president was seeking to undermine the independence of the central bank by appointing his supporters."

What is the subject of the clause "even (among Republicans) worried that the president..."?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93125/discussion-on-question-by-lexinton-ave-where-is-the-subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have quoted isn't a clause.

It parses as "even among [Republicans (who are) worried that ... ]"

**Edit**: I have been asked to expand this.

From what you say, you seem to be mis-parsing, thinking that "worried" is a past-tense verb, and asking what it its subject. It is not: it is a past participle, with adjectival force here.

The adjectival phrase "worried that the president was seeking to undermine the independence of the central bank by appointing his supporters" qualifies "Republicans". (You can see it as a reduction of the relative clause "who are worried that ... ")

Comment: With all due respect for your considerable reputation, this answer is terse and doesn't address the question. Maybe you're having a  bad day today. I'd suggest explaining why this is not a clause and clearly explaining where the OP can find the subject in the sentence and maybe how the section in the question relates to the subject. It needs more of something to be a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main clause of the example sentence is:

> Donald Trump’s desire to nominate Mr Cain had sparked a backlash

The verb is "spark" in the form 'had sparked". The subject is "Donald Trump’s desire to nominate Mr Cain" and the object is "backlash". The secondary clause "even among Republicans worried that the president was seeking..." explains who was included in that backlash.

Note thqt the main caluse works perfectly well as an independenat sentence.  The sentence could be recast into two sentences as:

> Donald Trump’s desire to nominate Mr Cain had sparked a backlash. This included Republicans worried that the president was seeking to undermine the independence of the central bank by appointing his own supporters.

In the recast sentences, the subject of the second is "this" which refers back to "backlash" in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence contains three clauses:

1. Donald Trump’s desire to nominate Mr Cain had sparked a backlash, even among Republicans. (The main clause)
2. (Who were) worried. (Dependent clause)
3. that the president was seeking to undermine the independence of the central bank by appointing his supporters. (Dependent clause)

The subject of the first dependent clause is the relative pronoun **who** which is elided, and its antecident is "Republicans".